# we have upgraded the angular version from 1.5 to 1.6 and now we are facing error in our application that page not found.Kindly sugges to resolve this

Tags: html, angularjs

we have upgraded the angular version from 1.5 to 1.6 and updated the dependencies in index.html file also . And now we are facing error in our application that page not found.Kindly sugges to resolve this.

Comment: Hi @anchal, please clarify what errors you are getting. Currently your question is too broad and difficult to answer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.